# Uploading a string to a restful client

Tags: groovy

I am trying to upload a string using java to a restful webclient. The client is set to receive multiform data using a filepath.

Is there a way other than creating a file to upload this string? Can I create a byte[] object, or do I need to make a temp file to upload it?

Example:

```
String s = "<tag>test</tag>"
String uri = "http://someserver.com/entity"
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)

LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> formParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>()
    formParams.add('1', s)

HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>>(formParams, httpHeaders)
ResponseEntity<Void> result = keystoreRestTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Void.class)
```

My response entity fails with 400 error. This is a curl that works:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -F "1=@/tmp/dummyFile.tmp" "http://someserver.com/entity"
```

Comment: the restful webclient's url you need to call, is it a GET or a POST ?

Comment: You are writing this code in pure Java ? Spring ? Using Apache's HttpClient ?

Comment: Sorry it was unclear. I attempted to clear it up. It is a POST request. Also, it is Groovy, not just Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but you can post a query string, almost like using get. Multiform shouldn't matter.

```
def address = 'http://posttestserver.com/post.php'.toURL()
def connection = address.openConnection()
connection.setRequestMethod("POST")
connection.doOutput = true

def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.outputStream)
writer.write('firstname=Test&lastname=Test2')
writer.flush()
writer.close()

connection.connect()
print connection.content.text
```

Comment: So, how do I do a file? I think my question is not clear... the backend seems to want a file for the parameter. I have generated the contents of the file via groovy and would like to upload those. Am I forced to make a temp file for that?